# QUERY ORDER BY en una tabla pivote LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, array, eloquent, model

Hola quizás mue puedan sugerir algo: Tengo 3 tablas ( empleado, tienda y una tabla pivote llamado empleado_tienda), resulta que esta tabla pivote contiene campos adiciones por ejemplo:

- FK_idTienda
- FK_idEmpleado
- FechCambio
- Documento

El modelo tienda es:

```
   public function empleado(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(empleado::class,'empleado_tienda', 'fk_idTienda','fk_idEmpleado')        
      ->withPivot('fechCambio', 'tipoDoc')->orderBy('fechCambio','DESC')->take(4); 
      }
```

En mi controller tengo:

```
   $MiTienda = Tienda::findOrFail($id);

   $todos = $MiTienda->empleado;
   Return $todos;
```

PROBLEMA:
Cuando retorno $todos, me muestra todos los registros, incluyendo los repetidos, y lo que necesito es mostrar solo la tienda con sus empleados.

IMPORTANTE: mi tabla pivote lo uso para tener un historial del paso del empleado por las diferentes tiendas y eso lo consigo por el campo 'fechCambio'(la fecha mas reciente me indica que el empleado pertenece a esa tienda)

PREGUNTA:
Como puedo mostrar unicamente la tienda con sus empleado? Creo que tengo que hacer dos consultas la primera extrayendo todos los datos de la tabla pivote y luego hacer un ORDER BY por el campo FechCambio y seleccionar únicamente el mas reciente, pero no se como hacerlo, me ayudan? gracias.

Comment: Que nombre tienen tus llaves primarias?

Comment: idTienda y idEmpleado, pero ya están definidas en  sus respectivos model's osea protect primaryKey = .....

Comment: Tienes que explicar bien como funciona la relación pivote. Ej: una tienda tiene muchos empleados y un empleado puede estar en varias tiendas (NxM). Luego que es lo que realmente quieres mostrar?

Comment: Un empleado pertenece a una sola tienda y una tienda alberga a muchos empleados , hasta aquí pareciera q la relación fuese de 1: N verdad? Pero  necesito tener el HISTORIAL de donde laboro el empleado. Es decir conocer sus movimientos entre tiendas.  Es por eso q hice una tabla PIVOTE.   En la cual se tiene 4 campos ( FK_idTienda, Fk_idEmpleado. FechaCambio,.documento)

Comment: Ahora necesito mostrar todos los empleados que pertenecen a una tienda, el problema es que se listan todos los registros repitiéndose un empleado varias veces ya que me muestra todos sus movimientos en el transcurso del tiempo. Necesito  filtrar sola la última tienda a la que pertenece.  Espero haberme explicado bien.